# Wordpress strip single shortcode from posts

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to strip just the `[gallery]` shortcodes in my blog posts. The only solution I found is a filter that I added to my functions.

```
function remove_gallery($content) {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_gallery');
```

It removes all shortcodes including `[caption]` which I need for images. How can I specify a single shortcode to exclude or include?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a shortcode or two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remove only the gallery shortcode , register a callback function that returns an empty string:

```
add_shortcode('gallery', '__return_false');
```

But this will only work with the callbacks. To do it statically, you can temporarily change the global state of wordpress to fool it:

```
/**
 * @param string $code name of the shortcode
 * @param string $content
 * @return string content with shortcode striped
 */
function strip_shortcode($code, $content)
{
    global $shortcode_tags;

    $stack = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array($code => 1);

    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);

    $shortcode_tags = $stack;
    return $content;
}
```

Usage:

```
$content = strip_shortcode('gallery', $content);
```

Comment: Nice one but you need to return other shortcodes, dont forget echo do_shortcode( $content ) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For me, worked with:

```
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', '__return_false');
```

If i try to strip_shortcode, they are remove all shortocodes and changing the final result

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get only the content, excluding any shortcodes, try something like that

```
global $post;
$postContentStr = apply_filters('the_content', strip_shortcodes($post->post_content));
echo $postContentStr;
```